# Gstreamer, how recover from (rtmpsink) error

Tags: python, error-handling, rtmp, gstreamer

I'm building streaming application in python with gstreamer.

The application writes data to rtmpsink and to filesink using a `tee` element. Starting and streaming works fine in ideal environment (local network) but what to do if there is a disconnect with the streaming server for example? I'm trying to figure out how to keep the pipeline running and thus keep writing to filesink after error occurs...

**What I'm trying to archive:**

1. At least I would like to keep my archive file (filesink) after error in streaming part (rtmpsink) occurs. Hereby we have some backup if error happens.
2. Manually reconnect to streaming server.
3. Build some mechanism to check for connection and reconnect streaming part (rtmpsink) if possible.

**Question(s):**

Is it possible to archive what I'm trying to do?

How can it be archived (dynamic pipeline / probes / extra elements )?

Any explanation, example or point to right direction will be very much appreciated.

***note:***

*Gst version:* gstreamer 1.3.90 (rtmpsink, faac, x264enc) 
*OS:* ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
*Streaming server:* wowza 4.x

**Test application (code):** [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75885675/gst-test-error.py) 
**Pipeline after startup(OK):** [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75885675/gst_startup.png)

**Pipeline after rtmpsink error(Failed to write data):** [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75885675/gst_error_rtmp.png) 
**Log snippet after rtmpsink error(Failed to write data):** [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75885675/gst_log.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how reliable a system you'll get with a single pipeline on this.  What I'd recommend doing is creating a two stage process:

```
1) audio -> encode -> tee -> filesink
                          -> shmsink 

2) shmsrc -> mux -> rtmpsink
```

Then create a wrapper script for the second pipeline.  Here's a sample of how to use these elements with a videotestsrc.  Note that the caps are really important--they have to be sufficiently detailed to know what's coming in over the shared memory.

> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert !
> ximagesink t. ! video/x-raw,width=400,height=400,format=BGRA ! shmsink
> wait-for-connection=false socket-path=/tmp/shr
>
> gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/shr !
> video/x-raw,width=400,height=400,format=BGRA,framerate=30/1 !
> videoconvert ! ximagesink

You could also try this approach with TCP/UDP instead of shared memory.  I don't have faac plugin installed but the pipeline would probably be something like this:

> audio -> faac -> rtpmp4apay -> udpsink host=localhost port=1919
>
> udpsrc port=1919 -> rtpmp4adepay -> mux -> rtmpsink

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still figuring out this approach (shmsink/shmsrc) and I have a lot of issues with 2nd process(shmsrc) and flvmux/rtmpsink. Only case that worked so far is only if I use in 1st process "... ! shmsink wait-for-connection=TRUE ..." otherwise streaming header get lost and audio is not playable...still working on it. Are there other approaches to my problem usecase besides one's you already named that you know of? (aka slip processes use shm src/sink or tcp/udp)

Comment: I'm not sure if AAC has some sort of "keyframe" packet that may be messing you up.  Have you tried adding an "aacparse" element to the 2nd process?  Another possibility is to use a simpler encoding for transferring the audio between processes--one that requires no parsing.

Comment: You may also want to investigate just using some other RTMP tools.  That rtmpsink element is listed under the gstreamer "plugins-bad", which means it's known to have some problems.  From your question I'm having trouble understanding if the failure point is between you and the RTMP server, or at your own computer.

Comment: Finally I found reason of all my aac/flv related issues, in short: 'aacparse' was buggy in my gstreamer and wasnt able to ouput any proper format. Aacparse was endlessly iterating through all known caps with warnings. Later I was able to replicate your approach but only with mp3 codec and mpegaudioparse successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I have also been working on trying to get a pipeline to reconnect to an RTMP server after errors. In principle I agree with [@mpr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27924950/146950) (using two pipelines connected with an shmsink/shmsrc pair) but I was unable to get that to work reliably, so I ended up using a different strategy.

I am using `rtmp2sink` and when that encounters an error it will post a message on the pipeline bus, and then return GST_FLOW_FLUSHING which causes the pipeline to flush everything. This is not what I was interested in, so I added a GhostPad in front of the `rtmp2sink` which catches the return value and turns it back into GST_FLOW_OK. At that point I also reset the `rtmp2sink` element to make it reconnect.

This seems pretty reliable, and at least against the RTMP server I was using I did not need to do anything special for handling keyframes from encoders.

All of this was tested with Gstreamer version 1.18.5. Here is a very basic example in Python showing this approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib

def _handle_message(_, message, loop):
    """handle messages posted to pipeline bus"""
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-of-stream")
        loop.quit()
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        if message.src.__class__.__name__ == "GstRtmp2Sink" and err.matches(
            Gst.ResourceError.quark(), Gst.ResourceError(err.code)
        ):
            resource_error = Gst.ResourceError(err.code)
            print(f"caught {resource_error} from rtmp2sink, ignoring")
        else:
            print(f"caught error {err} ({debug}), exiting")
            loop.quit()
    return True

def _wrap_rtmp_sink(rtmpsink: Gst.Element):
    """wrap RTMP sink to make it handle reconnections"""

    def _chain(pad: Gst.Pad, _, buffer: Gst.Buffer):
        internal_pad = pad.get_internal()
        result = internal_pad.push(buffer)
        if result == Gst.FlowReturn.FLUSHING or result == Gst.FlowReturn.ERROR:
            print(f"Restarting RTMP sink after {result}")
            rtmpsink.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            rtmpsink.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            return Gst.FlowReturn.OK

        return result

    sinkpad = rtmpsink.get_static_pad("sink")
    peer = sinkpad.get_peer()
    peer.unlink(sinkpad)

    ghost_pad = Gst.GhostPad.new("proxypad", sinkpad)
    ghost_pad.set_chain_function_full(_chain)
    peer.link(ghost_pad)
    ghost_pad.activate_mode(Gst.PadMode.PUSH, True)

    # hang on to GhostPad to avoid Python garbage collecting it
    rtmpsink._ghost_pad = ghost_pad

def main():
    Gst.init(None)
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
        f"""
        videotestsrc
            ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1
            ! avenc_h264_videotoolbox
            ! h264parse
            ! flvmux.video

        audiotestsrc
            ! faac
            ! flvmux.audio

        flvmux name=flvmux streamable=true
            ! queue
            ! rtmp2sink name=rtmp location=rtmp://10.1.0.10/test/test
    """
    )

    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", _handle_message, loop)

    _wrap_rtmp_sink(pipeline.get_by_name("rtmp"))

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    loop.run()
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```